# Underscore.js script not rendering in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Noob to JS and underscore --

In the following simple code I am trying to iterate through var animalNames using underscore (_.each fxn) but when I run the code in Node in terminal it just goes right back to cmd prompt ie. nothing runs. Please help explain what's going.

```
function AnimalMaker(name) {
    return { speak: function () { console.log("my name is ", name); } };
};
var animalNames = ['', '', ''];

var farm = [];

us.each(animalNames, function (name) {
farm.push(AnimalMaker(name));
});
```

Comment: Can you include more code? We can't tell if you're bringing in underscore. Also can you include any errors that you're seeing?

Comment: Your code isn't calling the `speak` method on your farm animals... Is that your problem? Or are you getting errors?

Comment: *"but when I run the code in Node in terminal."* Then what? I think you accidentally something.

Comment: Thanks, Bart. So what do I need to do to call the farm animals? Invoke the speak method explicitly? this call at the end of the code: AnimalMaker(); gives an output: {speak: [Function] }

Comment: `AnimalMaker` creates an object with a `speak` method. You still need to invoke that method to make the object speak... Check my full answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `map` method is more appropriate in this case, because you're mapping an array of names to an array of Animals

```
// I renamed AnimalMaker
// In JS it's a convention to capitalize constructors and keep normal functions camel-case
var createAnimal = function(name) {
    return {
        speak: function() { console.log("my name is", name); }
    };
};

var names = ["Chicken", "Cow", "Pig"];
var animals = us.map(names, createAnimal);
```

With this code you've created a list of animals. Now you still need to make those animals speak:

```
us.each(animals, function(animal) {
    animal.speak();
});
```

Or use `invoke` to call a method for each object in a list:

```
us.invoke(animals, "speak");
```

Without underscore (native javascript in node.js) you could also write:

```
var animals = names.map(createAnimal);
animals.forEach(function(animal) {
    animal.speak();
});
```

Comment: `us.invoke(animals, "speak")` ftw!